# Misleading Epic badge progress

Tags: bug, reputation, badges, badge-progress, daily-reputation-badges

I verified it to `Epic` badge but probably the same is for `Legendary`. Please look at below screen

[image: Epic progress]

The problem is with today's rep. It doesn't actually calculates todays reputation but it seems it calculates today's reputation cap.

For example today I've already have reputation over +300 and I got +1 to days earned (this info is displayed and calculated correctly) however as `today's rep` it's not over 300, but it's showing at the moment my reputation to reputation cap after which no `+10` will be added to my account today.

For me it's quite misleading. It should either display only today's reputation here, or change this `today's rep` to `today's rep cap` and add another `today's rep` with valid value

Comment: Reported before, they are not in a hurry to fix it.  You only see rep from upvotes, not from bounties and accepts.  You have +110 from upvotes right now.