# Confusion over awarding of Epic badge

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

*(I note [Misleading epic badge progress](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313676/misleading-epic-badge-progress) as a potential duplicate - but I'm not totally convinced it's exactly the same problem)*

According to the badges page, I've just been awarded the Epic badge:

[image]

But I didn't actually think I should have it yet anyway:

[image]

Only 45 days, not the requisite 50. So why have I earned the Epic badge?

Comment: [I'm just saying... ;)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/194720))

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ok ok ok :)

Comment: The /reputation page is not an accurate count of how many days qualify for the badge. The badge criteria is more complex than just "number of days where reputation > 200" and the numbers will not always match.

Comment: Maybe you had 5 days at exactly 200 reputation.

Comment: @animuson I thought the whole purpose of that page was to be completely accurate.

Comment: @Stijn It is completely accurate. The badge just has more complicated criteria, and that number is not the same thing as what qualifies for the badge. There are plenty of numbers across our sites (like number of edits) which don't line up to how many qualify for the badge. They're just different numbers.

Comment: @animuson in that case, is the bug in the description of the badge? "Earn 200 daily reputation 50 times" is pretty uncomplicated, but you're saying that it's not really judged by that criterion.

Comment: @AndyTurner The difference may be what's stated in the [full badge description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188731) on MSE: _"Down votes cast or received do not count towards this badge."_ That line in the reputation page probably takes downvotes into account, while the badge does not.