# Awarded "Epic" badge out of nowhere

Tags: bug, daily-reputation-badges

Okay, I understand that the criteria for this badge [are more complex](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338069) than the stated "Earn 200 daily reputation 50 times" (although I couldn't find any actual detailed explanation).

But I was just notified that I got this badge... the problem is, I [didn't](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel?tab=reputation) gain **anywhere near** 200 daily reputation in the past day.

Or yesterday.

Or the day before.

Or in recent memory.

Even only counting positive-rep events, I can't find a day where I gained even as much as 50 reputation, since **September 5** - and that's clearly an outlier.

What's going on?

Comment: You were [awarded the badge on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic?userid=523612), where it counts the reputation you would have received if meta reputation were a thing.

Comment: I guess the main problem here is that it is really unclear on which particular site you gained the badge. It is also really wonky that you get reputation-based badges on a site which does not have reputation. I guess it secretly kind of still does. Can we make it anymore confusing?

Comment: @Gimby, it does, and not really secretly. If you add a meta to your communities in the right burger menu, you'll see reputation there.